# htaccess , can't access homepage

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set locally a project that run on the web on a NGIX server. This is the htaccess i have downloaded:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~sitename/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~sitename/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to run it locally on an Apache server(on mamp) . It have placed the project in a folder on the server root:

http://localhost/sitename/

But i get a blank page. 
I can access a specific internal page (and only that one) if i remove the tilde 
`~`
Even without the tilde, i can't access the homepage of the project.
So what i'm doing wrong? 
How the tilde works in this context ?

EDIT

my mod_rewrite is loaded/enabled

Comment: first question is mod rewrite activated in your mamp?

Comment: You ask: "How the tilde works in this context ?"... We answer: why don't you simply read the documentation of the tool you use? It is of excellent quality and available with a simple google search for "apache mod_rewrite".